# How to clean a toilet water flush "limitator" (bump?)?

Tags: water, toilet

*Apologies for the non-technical expressions, I am not a native English speaker.*

I have the following embedded water flush:

[image]

[image]

The problems with that water flush are the following:

- it usually flushes fine (90% of the time)
- sometimes, when full, the blocking mechanism does not work and the water keeps on flowing (1/5 cases of the remaining 10%)
- usually the water influx stops, then after a moment a tiny stream of water sips, with a faint sound of water (4/5 of cases of the remaining 10%)
- sometimes, when the water stopped normally a while ago, there is a small eruption of water flowing for about 2 seconds, and then back to normal.

I pinpointed the problem to "device A" - it moves up and down by approx 3 cm (ca. 1") and seems to be the "stopper" for the water. When something is wrong (the tiny stream of water for instance), I move it up and down and it is back to normal for some time.

The installation is about 8 years old and I suspect that the accumulation of calcium is creating too much friction for "device A" to move freely. The fact that this is not a constant behaviour could be explained by that too (I guess.

**My question:** is it something I can clean (by immersing in vinegar for instance), or should I  plan to change that part (if it is changeable at all).

**Bonus question:** is this something someone like me (you can guess from the description that I am closer to an art major than a plumber, but I am ready to dig in) can reasonably do without damages to the family peace?

The device brand name is Geberit Aqua Clean

[image]

<sub>I noticed on the first picture that there is a guest in the water flush, a small spider</sub>

Comment: I resolved a similar problem with such a system on holiday last year by making certain the levers which engage the 90 degree cams to the switch plate ran as straight and true as possible, and taking up the slack on the screw adjusters for the switches to prevent people pushing it too hard and throw the siphon so far up it seems never to come down unless tapped.  Both of these are workarounds (preventing over stressing the mechanism rather than stopping binding) and I'll be interested to know how one is supposed to adjust them, particularly given the impossibility of getting at them...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with mine.
Though a different mechanism, I solved it with a little!! Vaseline where the flapper on the bottom of the tank attaches. Device A in your picture looks like a floater which would not stop a leak but would stop the tank from overflowing.